# Не вытаскивает ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$html = '<a href="/111/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a>
текст
<a href="/3233/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a>';
 
preg_replace_callback('#<a\s.*/a>#usi', function (array $matches) {
    preg_match_all('/<a.*?href=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?>/i', $matches[0], $url);
    print_r($url[1][0]);
    print_r('<br>');
}, $html);
```

Не понимаю, почему достает, обрабатывает только первую ссыклу, второй нету.

Как можно заменить html ссылку на содержимое атрибута href

```
($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $i => $el){
    $href = $el->getAttribute('href');
    $lintext = $el->nodeValue;
    print_r($el);          
}
```

Comment: Пора бы вам познакомиться с https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php  для работы с html, а парсинг оного с помощью. регулярок забыть как в страшном сне

Comment: Хорошо, первый вопрос ($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML($html);

Comment: Как не выставляя условия, то есть переменная $html пуста из-за этого ошибка. DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty

Comment: Собственно не выставляя условия, возможно избежать возникновения ошибки?

Comment: Второй вопрос, как в цикле foreach. Собственно поменять ссылку скажем на $href. Снова прибегать к регулярке для поиска и замены?

Answer (score 1):

Вам верно указали на то, что парсинг HTML регулярными выражениями -- занятие неблагодарное. Дело в том, что HTML довольно сложен и вы не всегда можете написать правильную регулярку. Например, в документе могут быть [якоря](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) типа `<a name="top"></a>`, кавычки атрибутов могут отсутствовать `<a href=https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-value-(unquoted)-state>parsing</a>`. Чтобы не ошибиться, лучше воспользоваться готовым, протестированным на таких случаях парсером.

Но для общего развития обратите внимание на так называемую [жадность квантификаторов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.repetition.php) (поищите "жадность" на странице). Ваш шаблон `<a\s.*/a>` захватывает не первую ссылку, а весь html целиком.

Теперь по поводу замены элемента в DOMDocument. Вы можете собрать все нужные вам элементы ссылок и их href'ы в массив на замену и потом обойти его и воспользоваться методом [replaceWith](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domchildnode.replacewith.php). Обратите внимание, что делать замену надо в отдельном цикле. getElementsByTagName возвращает не массив, а итерируемый объект списка нод, поэтому обход прервётся, если вы будете менять документ во время итерации.

DomDocument интересно работает с кодировкой, поэтому вам возможно придётся повозиться с этим, если в вашем HTML не указана кодировка. Вы можете найти решения погуглив "php dom encoding" или порывшись в комментариях в документации на php.net.

Comment: Могу подсказать, чтобы с кодировкой не было проблем она должна быть явно указана в HTML тегом. Вместо getElementsByTagName рекомендую использовать язык запросов XPath https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php сэкономит много времени, и не придется делать отдельный цикл